# Does Azure App Service support extended ACLs?

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, ip-restrictions

I am wondering how the IP restrictions in Azure App service works. The documentation states:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-ip-restrictions

"The IP Restrictions capability is implemented in the App Service front-end roles, which are upstream of the worker hosts where your code runs. Therefore, IP Restrictions are effectively network ACLs."

But they are not network ACLs, but firewall rules on a different machine - is that a valid statement?

Is there any way to configure extended ACLs (with port based rules) if that is not the case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Azure web apps only have port 80 & 443 open so there really is no way to do port based rules.  If you really want to lock down your web app you can [disable the FTP](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/deploy-ftp#enforce-ftps) functionality in the Application Settings and you can [force HTTPS](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/benjaminperkins/2017/11/30/how-to-make-an-azure-app-service-https-only/) under the Custom Domain settings.  Additionally, if you want to apply Network Security Groups to a Web App, you can deploy it to an [App Service Environment (ASE v2)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/environment/create-ilb-ase) which is an isolated instance that can be deployed with a private IP.

You can also use an [Application Gateway with Web App Firewall (WAF)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-gateway/waf-overview) to protect your web app. If you are planning on using an App Gateway with a multi-tenant web app (non-ASE) see our documentation [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-gateway/create-web-app).